# Concatenate fields and then filter the results in php/mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have three fields in mongo db collection studentTbl:

- first_name
- middle_name
- last_name

I am creating Search module using mongo db in php application and have tried the following lines of code

```
            $query = array('$or' => array(                                      
                                    array("registration_temp_perm_no" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                                    array("roll_no" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                                    array(
                                          array(
                                               '$project' => array(
                                               'fullname' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$last_name')),
                                               )
                                          ),
                                          array(
                                               '$match' => array(
                                               'fullname' => array('$regex' => $arg, '$options' => 'i'),
                                                )
                                            )
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                          array(
                                               '$project' => array(
                                               'fullname' => array('$concat' => array('$first_name', ' ', '$middle_name')),
                                               )
                                          ),
                                          array(
                                               '$match' => array(
                                               'fullname' => array('$regex' => $arg, '$options' => 'i'),
                                                )
                                            )
                                    ),
                                    array("first_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                                    array("middle_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                                    array("last_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                                    array("email" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                                    array("guardian_name" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                                    array("phone1" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                                    array("dob" => new MongoRegex("/$arg/i")),
                                )
                  );
```

if there is a document in studentTbl with the following details

- first_name : "Pooja"
- middle_name: "Mahavir"
- last_name: "Sharma"

Now if we give "Pooja" in $args, it should fetch all the students with name "pooja", and if we give "sharma" in  $args, it should fetch all the students with name sharma. If $args contains "poo", it should fetch all the students whose name contains "poo" whether in end or beginning or in the middle like "poonam" or "tapoo" etc if whole name is given then it should fetch accordingly and if $args contains "pooja sharma", it should also fetch on the basis of first name and last name as well.
The above code is fetching all the records. Also please note that other search criteria should be maintained.

Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: try replace $and with $or

Comment: now it fetching all the students